# Unable to set font on Node.js using Fabric.js

Tags: node.js, canvas, fonts, fabricjs

I am using fabric to create image but its says "undefined is not a function".

I am not able to set the font.

```
 var fs = require('fs'),
 fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
 canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(300, 250);

 var font = new canvas.Font('Ubuntu', __dirname + '/fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf');
```

canvas.Font is undefined.

fabric@1.4.0, canvas@1.0.4

Comment: Are you following the instructions from [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/) under Custom fonts in Fabric on Node. It works for me.

Comment: yes. i checked the cairo dependancies.